# how to implement where condition in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The data returned in the following format:

in the controller

```
[User] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => Vikas

        [last_name] => tyagi

        [phone_no] => 0234

        [mobile_no] => 0

        [location_id] => 1

        [state_id] => 2
    )
```

and i have table locations

```
           field      id        location_name

           value       1        chandigarh
```

i want to fire that query

select location_name from locations where location_id=1;

how can i do it in cake php

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, one is simpler but more tedious, the other requires a setup but easier to use in the future.

First way:

```
$locationName = $this->Location->field('location_name', array('id' => $user['User']['location_id']));
```

Second way:

Setup a belongsTo relationship in your User model and hasOne in your Location model

```
user.php:
public $belongsTo = array('Location');

location.php
public $hasOne = array('User');
```

This way, whenever you do a ->find() from your user model, the Location info would also be returned.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1041/hasOne